# Alternative to tinychat?

Tags: video, chat, video-chat

I really hate the tinychat interface. I'm looking for a product that provides an:

- XMPP/IRC gateway (to text chat obviously)
- No external registration required (as in Google/Aim/Yahoo account creation)
- Video chatting for those who want it?

Anyone know of a service?

Comment: why is there a close vote?

Comment: TinyChat doesn't even support the basics like /me and with the video integration an IRC gateway seems unlikely.

Comment: I don't need an IRC gateway to video chat.. I don't care about that feature..

Comment: meebo won't do it?

Comment: meebo has chat rooms? I thought it was just an IM interface?

Comment: meebo has since discontinued it's chat room servies.

Answer (score 2):

Lifetime.fm satisfies #2 and #3 of your requirements.
Text chat with optional video chat up to 9 people.
No external registration is required.

Comment: *Looks* good. If it didn't register every keypress twice, it would almost be usable!

Answer (score 0):

Try ChatterPlace. It has all the features of TinyChat and Paltalk and more. Everything is free and you can totally customize your created chat room, background, layout etc. Another good thing is that you can allow guest access or make your room private. You also get admin powers and can add your friends as moderators. Video chat is another free feature along with text chat as standard. Here is the site http://chatterplace.com I hope this helps?